# How to add fields dynamically in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add fields dynamically in Django 1.8.

Here's my models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here's my admin.py

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

I've tried to use [Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin), but I can only add a new book also.

I want to be able to add many books to one author dynamically.
Something like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I've changed AuthorAdmin to this:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

[image]

But instead of one checkbox with "N" options, I want "N" textboxes to choose the books.

Answer (score 3):

You got your cardinalities the wrong way round. As you wrote it, the relationship is "An author has one book, a book has many authors", while you obviously wanted "A book has one author, an author has many books" - or possibly "a book as one or many authors, an author has one or many books".

In the first case, you have to remove the `ForeignKey` in `Author` and add a `ForeignKey` to `Book` in `Author` - and use an `AdminInline` in `Author` if you want to be able to add books to an author from the `AuthorAdmin`.

In the second case, you want a `ManyToManyField`, which can be in either `Book` or `Author`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ManyToMany` field for books:

```
books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for `ManyToMany`.

Comment: A `ManyToManyField` implies that a `Book` can have more than one author. While it makes sense wrt/ "real world", it's not _necessarily_ the appropriate domain model for the OP's application.